# redeclare a custom PHP function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress child theme, I did not work on wordpress a lot but from what i know some function are added to WP them like

```
add_action( 'init', 'rd_share_panel' );
```

the function i want to edit 'rd_share_panel' is declared in theme files and call as a normal PHP function to output some HTML code, it does not have an add_action

I would like to override it in my child theme
I can't just redeclare because i get an error

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare rd_share_panel()...
```

Any way to do it?

Comment: Try this : `<?php remove_action( $tag, $function_to_remove, $priority ); ?>`.

Comment: is a normal function it doesn't have a WP add_action

Comment: Why you want to redeclare  that function?

Comment: because i have 2 options edit original function, modifying the original theme and that would brake on theme upgrade, work on child theme but i guess that child theme function are declare before loading parent theme. I guess i have no way to do it without editing parent theme

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145422/redeclare-a-function-in-a-child-theme Sadly, because the parent doesn't wrap it in `function_exists`, your options are limited. Child themes' `function.php` files are included before the parent specifically so they can override parent functions, but the parent has to be well-written to allow this.

Comment: I guess there is no way to do it without editing parent theme, thanks